# In my solidity file I have a parser Error but the line where truffle tells me the error has occurred is blank

Tags: truffle-contract, truffle-test, truffle-compile

I am building out a token and while testing using truffle my file failed to compile.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract Token {

    using SafeMath for uint;

    //Variables
    string public name = "Qubit";
    string public symbol = "QBT";
    uint256 public decimals = 18;
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;

    //Events
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    
    constructor() public {
        totalSupply = 1000000 * (10 ** decimals);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_to != address(0));
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = balanceOf[msg.sender].sub(_value); 
        balanceOf[_to] = balanceOf[_to].add(_value);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    //Approve tokens
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns(bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value; 
    }
```

> project:/src/contracts/Token.sol:37:1: ParserError: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected.

First thing I did was looked at line 37. Line 37 was blank when I deleted and ran the file again it changed to line 36 and so on.

I have checked my code and compared it with the course video I am following to build out this token but can't seem to catch my mistake.

Comment: I think you should give me more information

Comment: Please include the source code. Sometimes the error is in a previous line.

Comment: @zmy I have edited the question and added the source code thank you!

Comment: @Ismael I added the source code to the question thank you for your help!

Comment: @Devin I tried the contract and solc doesn't show any error message. I don't know what can be wrong with truffle, you can try removing the build/ directory or moving the whole project `truffle compile --all` should force compilation of all contracts. Bonus: from the spec [EIP-20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) decimals is `uint8`.